# Want to create a button on the nav bar of Outlook (like a module add-in) to run code

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create a small Outlook add-in module whose icon will live in the navigation bar next to mail, calendar, people etc.
I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/extension-module-outlook-add-ins), but cant get it to even show the icon in Outlook. I did successfully add it in Office 365 OWA, but it never shows in Outlook. The problem may be that I didnt install the local server as directed, but that is not really what I want my project to do. At this point I'm just trying to get the icon added and maybe attach some of my own sample code.

I did try as a totally crazy idea putting the various icons in a folder on my web server and then changing the links in the code to point to them (https://localhost:8080/Associate-16.png ---> (https://mywebsite.com/testimages/Associate-16.png)

I would actually rather do the whole thing in VBA if there is a way to add an icon to the nav bar (not the ribbon) and run VBA code.

I did a lot of searching but the above link was the only sample I could find to create an add-in module.

Any guidance or maybe some help finding some other sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Module extensions are only supported by Outlook 2016 or later on Windows. Also you may take at the sample add-in solution at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-ModuleExtension .

Comment: Yes, it is for Ol2016 and greater.  The sample you point to is the one from my link. I cant get it to show in outlook even though OWA shows it is installed. Im looking for another example that doesnt require running a local server.

Comment: Try to scaffold a new add-in solution and make all the modifications the article you are referring to describes.

Comment: I did but cant get it to show in OL

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No error. It show as added in the OWA add-in page, but when I open Outlook desktop app based on the sample description it should add an icon to the nav pane of Outlook (I expanded the list to show all icons). As I said before I am not running the local server as the demo talks about, but I did upload the parent directory and lib directory from the example to my web server and can open them in a web browser.. i of course changed all of the local https links to point to the web

Comment: Did you install your add-in in Outlook for desktop separately?

Comment: Maybe that is my problem. I assumed that when I add it to the OWA it will sync into the desktop version. How do I add a JS based plugin to the desktop version. You cant add it like a COM addin?

Comment: See [Outlook on the desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing?tabs=windows#outlook-on-the-desktop)

Comment: I looked at your link for side-loading. My OL2016 doesnt have the add-on icon on the ribbon or overflow menu or have an option to add it to ribbon. I have a button under  File Add-ins which does the same thing, launch the browser and take you to O365 to add a custom add-in but it never shows in OL desktop (this is the way I have been adding since the beginning).  I tried with a friends OL2019 and the extension works. So it is my OL version. strange because they say it should work with OL2016

Comment: Hi @user1561769, I am unable to replicate this, as the billable hours example shows for me. What is your version of outlook?

Comment: Im using Outlook 2016

Comment: Hi @user1561769, Sorry, I meant the build number. This can be found in File -> Office Account  and should be a number in the format 16.0.XXXXX.YYYYY

Comment: file - account -about : 16.0.4266.1001 32-bit
outlook.exe - properties - details - file version :16.0.5134.1000

I have tried on 3 different computers, all with same outlook version but different Office 365 accounts.  same problem

Comment: Hi @user1561769, You would need the latest version of outlook 2016 (5394) for module add-ins. Also, we highly recommend to migrate your add-in to the new Teams Module add-in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/teams-toolkit-overview#create-an-outlook-add-in-project), as module add-ins will eventually not be supported.

Comment: I thought I had the latest version.

Would you have a link to update the MSI version to that version?

Comment: Hi @user1561769 - This should help (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/office-updates-msi) However, please be aware that Outlook 2016 is outdated and any issues encountered will not be fixed